# Event handling ,Data Structure and program design ,java

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures, event-handling

i have a list of event types

```
enum EventType {
    ErrorEvent, StatusEvent, DataEvent 
}
```

one listener can register to more than a event by calling

```
addListener (Listener listener,EventType eventType) {
    // to do 
}
```

can any one suggest, what data structure can i use to store all of these information 
(listener and its associated event types)

or anyother java API classes already supports this ?

array of arrays or 
list of list looks ugly to me.

Please suggest

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use an EnumMap of lists (or sets if you want listeners to be unique).

```
private Map<EventType, List<Listener>> listeners = 
  new EnumMap<EventType, List<Listener>>(EventType.class);

public void addListener(Listener listener, EventType eventType) {
  if(null == listeners.get(eventType)) {
    listeners.put(eventType, new ArrayList<Listener>());
  }

  listeners.get(eventType).add(listener);
}

private void sendEvent(Event e) {
  if(listeners.get(e.getType() == null) {
    return;
  }

  for(Listener listener : listeners.get(e.getType()) {
    listener.eventOccurred(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're, like so many others, in the beginning of reinvent the famous [PropertyChangeListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)/[PropertyChangeEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html)/[PropertyChangeSupport](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) mechanism. So, do yourself a favor, and instead of creating your own event/listener hierarchy, reuse that generic one, which is specifically tailored for beans property changes (and as a consequence all Java objects).